# Ubuntu 16.04 issue connecting wired and wireless connections to the router

Tags: wireless, network-manager, ethernet, routing

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.  I have a pretty simple networking setup, a router with both wifi and wired connections. Separately I can connect to the router using either wifi or ethernet and both work well reliably. However, when I have both connected at the same time, the internet stops working and pages stop loading.
I have tried looking up a similar question online, but most of the folks are trying to connect to connect to different networks. My situation seems pretty basic but I have been unable to find a solution. Any help is very much appreciated.

```
Working LAN Only:
$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s31f6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c8:5b:ff:aa:bb:cc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.164/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global enp0s31f6
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::6916:d619:b127:b0a7/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:a4:ff:aa:bb:cc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:ff:4a:f3:d0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

$ ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp0s31f6  proto static  metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s31f6  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp0s31f6  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.164  metric 100 

Working Wifi Only:
$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s31f6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c8:5b:ff:aa:bb:cc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:a4:ff:aa:bb:cc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.163/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global wlp1s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::631:b92:a78:cc61/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:ff:4a:f3:d0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

$ ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp1s0  proto static  metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp1s0  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp1s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.163  metric 600 

Non-working Wifi and LAN
$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s31f6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c8:5b:ff:aa:bb:cc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.164/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global enp0s31f6
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::6916:d619:b127:b0a7/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:a4:ff:aa:bb:cc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.163/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global wlp1s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::631:b92:a78:cc61/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:ff:4a:f3:d0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

$ ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp0s31f6  proto static  metric 100 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp1s0  proto static  metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s31f6  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp0s31f6  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.164  metric 100 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp1s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.163  metric 600
```

Comment: anything in [this](https://aleksz-programming.blogspot.com/2013/01/using-wifi-and-network-cable-at-same.html) resource which helps?

Comment: [edit] your question and show us `ip addr;ip route` in both of the "working"  states and in the "failed" state.

Comment: @24601 I have used the "Use this connection only for resources on its network" before when working with one local and one internet connection, but in my current situation that does not help since both connections are equivalent.

Comment: @waltinator please take a look at the updated question

Comment: Your problem is you have conflicting routing going on here - the system won't know how to route traffic proper

Comment: @ThomasWard I see that as a potential problem, but this is a standard setup for many laptop use cases. Windows seems to be able to handle this out of the box.  How can I set it up so that I can seamlessly plug / unplug and have it pick the best connection.

Comment: @Vik Windows 'seems to handle this' by prioritizing Ethernet to Wifi.  It has extra tools that effectively 'suspend' the Ethernet connection and use the other.  Comparing Windows and Linux is not going to help here.  There's no direct equivalent to this in Linux to my knowledge (though it's probably doable I don't personally know how it is).  Also, **most** laptops nowadays don't include Ethernet ports so it's *not* a standard setup in the common environments - even in the workplace.

Comment: @ThomasWard that is not a fair assumption, docking stations do have Ethernet ports and are common in a corporate setting.  My routing table looks the same and I have no issues with both enabled.  I am on Ubuntu 18 but I don't remember having this issue on 16.

Comment: What model laptop?

Comment: @rtaft That presupposed the companies BUY docking stations that work that way - however in a Windows case it's going to override the Wifi by defaulting to Ethernet, you'd need some pretty heavy-duty network management that is **NOT** out of the box for this kind of dual-home environment simultaneously to work (also most networks DON'T use the same IP pool for their wifi and ethernet environments... even in a Corporate environment, and that I know as a network engineer, they usually use separate IP spaces and rulesets)

Comment: @rtaft its a Lenovo ThinkPad, actually now that I think about it, my network is slightly different from just a basic router.  I use DNS from pihole which also serves as a DHCP server, so my router is 192.168.1.1 and my DHCP and DNS server is 192.168.1.150. I wonder if that complicates things.

Comment: @ThomasWard I agree in a corporate environment the IP pools are usually different, my test though is both to the same home router, same DNS, same DHCP, and seems to prioritize traffic over the wired network as its listed first in the routing table.

Comment: @Vik can you ping the router when connected to both?

Comment: @rtaft yes when connected to both, I can ping the router and ping pihole / DNS server. I can also ping externally to say google by IP 172.217.10.228, but it looks like the DNS lookup fails since I can't ping www.google.com.

Comment: If you use Google's DNS 8.8.8.8 does it resolve?. Just to isolate the problem. Maybe the problem is in your DNS Server.

Comment: @CarlesMateo I used network manager to set DNS to 8.8.8.8 and tested both connections individually. I know it is correctly set since I started seeings ADs in both. Again, the internet works for both separately but not when both are connected.

Answer (score 0):

More than one interface on same sub-net, is not expected in network design.

Even you setup interface to have a working static routing, the other devices will not be aware of your device setup. So your device send packet on one interface, other devices don't care, their packets are not directed to specific interface but just IP. So coming packets are undefined on which interface to receive them.

More info check [How to connect two network interfaces on the same subnet?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/30564) yet not the canonical answer.

I am not the expert but experienced this multiple times. This is more generic than Duplicate IP on same network. It seems difficult to make every app, know about (two sets of IP/DEV) send on one and receive on both.

Some laptop manufacturer implement a feature in BIOS/UEFI firmware to switch automatically Wifi(WLAN)/MobileData(WWAN) interface OFF if detected a Wired interface is ON (direct cable or through Dock station).

At least, I use it on Dell Precision/Latitude. Settings in Dell: [Wireless is disabled when Ethernet is connected](https://www.dell.com/community/Networking-Internet-Bluetooth/Wireless-is-disabled-when-Ethernet-is-connected/td-p/4529436)